# How do I rename the extension of an individual file through Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way of renaming a single file's extension. I've looked into a bunch of methods online, but all of them seem to be for converting files in bulk, using basic `.each` do blocks. In those blocks, I noticed FileUtils was used a lot, but I supposed it was because that a directory path was given that its usage was imminent. I know how to do the bulk method, I'm just not sure about an individual method, w/ something along the lines of:
    def convert_file_extension(input_file)
      ...
    end

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I doubt there's a better way than grepping for files and renaming each of them separately.

Comment: Probably, but the disadvantage with bulk conversion is that you can't choose a specific file to change.

Answer (score 1):

This statement does the trick:

```
def self.rename_file(input_file, output_file)
  File.rename(input_file, output_file) if !File.exist?(output_file)
end
```

Thanks to @7stud & @ostapische!

Answer (score 0):

```
def change_ext(fname, new_ext)
  i = fname.rindex(".") 
  i ? (fname[0...i] + new_ext) : (fname + new_ext)
end

puts change_ext("/usr/local/file", ".xyz")
puts change_ext("/usr/local/file.txt", ".xyz")


--output:--
/usr/local/file.xyz
/usr/local/file.xyz
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there a possibility that the input file's contents could be overwritten? Is the file automatically saved so the change sticks?

Comment: Changing a string in a ruby program does nothing to any file's on your computer--no more than changing a variable called your_name changes your birth certificate at the county registrar's office. However, the File class has a method named rename, which will change a file's name on your computer.

Comment: There is no possibility that the file's contents will be overwritten because you are not writing to the file.  `File.rename("oldname", "newname")`

Comment: There is a potential problem though:  if you have two files named `/dir1/dir2/abc` and `/dir1/dir2/abc.txt` and you rename them both with a .xyz extension you will end up with both files named: `/dir1/dir2/abc.xyz`, and if you then rename each file, the second renaming would overwrite the first file.  But you can always employ an if statement first that checks if `File.exists?(new_fname)`.

Comment: How about changing the `File.rename` line to `File.save(input_file)`?

Comment: There's no such method.

Comment: @7stud is right `File.rename(oldname, newname) if !File.exist?(newname)` works like a charm. If file with `newname` exists than `oldname` file don't be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the solutions given above:

You can take apart a file path into the individual components: File.dirname yields the directory part, File.extname returns the extension. File.basename gives you just the filename, optionally with extension removed. In this way, you can also easily construct the new file name (and, of course, use then File.rename to actually change the filename).